# Xamarin, get the screen of cellphone blocked till the user press a specific button

Tags: c#, xamarin

I beginning with Xamarin and I have a doubt:

is it possible with Xamarin, to block the screen?

Example: my app is playing a video on full screen mode. The user touch the screen or the hard buttons of his device, but the video continue to play like the user hadn`t touched the screen, etc...

The only way to stop the execution of the video, is when he presses some especific button.

Is that possible?

How can I achieve that?

Comment: If it's possible to do natively, then it's possible to do in Xamarin.

Comment: **NO**, not in Xamarin or Native.